# Sign transaction on behalf of a 3rd party wallet

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, binance-smart-chain, ethers.js

Is it possible to authorize a server to sign transactions on user's behalf?

Flow:

1. User connects wallet in the frontend
2. User authorizes server to sign transactions for their wallet
3. Server listens for events on the chain
4. Server signs and executes transaction on user's behalf

I'm new to web3 overall, so I don't even know where to start looking for a solution. I do know about `approve` on contracts. Do I have to deploy such a contract and use that?

Naturally, I don't want to ask my users for their private key/mnemonic.

Comment: Can you specify what action do you need to perform on the user's behalf? Sending native transactions is impossible by design (it needs to be signed by the private key of the sender) but for some actions regarding smart contracts (e.g. transferirng tokens for authorized users on **your own** - not external - contract) you could make use of the EDCSA signature.

Comment: PancakeSwap router - definitely not mine - is the target contract. So I guess that's not going to work then, right?

Is there a way to achieve my scenario, at all? I read about relay networks, but then I'd have to pay all the gas fees.
I guess custodial wallets would be another option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to authorize a server to sign transactions on user's behalf?

No.

Or: only if your smart contracts support some kind of specially signed messages, but they aren't compatible with any normal Ethereum transactions and this is your application-specific logic.

Comment: Thanks for answering this. I went with a custodial scheme.